# Replace values of a Pandas dataframe's Column based on values of another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Current Pandas Dataframe:

```
   Chunk_Num |reading_id |imei
   ____________________________________
0    0          4       35475624
1    0          6       35475624
2    0          6       35475624
3    0          7       35475624
4    0          7       35475624
5    0          11      35475624
```

I need to group every 2 Indexes into 1 Chunk_Num.

That is:

1) assign rows at index 0,1  to Chunk_Num=0

2) assign rows at index 2,3  to Chunk_Num=1

3) assign rows at index 4,5  to Chunk_Num=2

Needed o/p:

```
   Chunk_Num |reading_id |imei
   ____________________________________
0    0          4       35475624
1    0          6       35475624
2    1          6       35475624
3    1          7       35475624
4    2          7       35475624
5    2          11      35475624
```

Right now, I have:

```
index_list= [0,1,2,3,4,5]
chunk_list_elements=[0,1,2]

for i , c in zip(index_list, chunk_list_elements): # 3rd el of chunk_list, is mapped to 3rd el of index_list.
    transition2_df.loc[i,'Chunk_Num']= c
    transition2_df.loc[i+1,'Chunk_Num']= c
    i= i+2
display(transition2_df)
```

And that gives me:

```
   Chunk_Num |reading_id |imei
   ____________________________________
0    0          4       35475624
1    1          6       35475624
2    2          6       35475624
3    2          7       35475624
4    0          7       35475624
5    0          11      35475624
```

I'm not sure what I'm missing here. I'm open to other approaches as well besides using `zip()`.

Please help.

Comment: `df.index//2` if you using the default range index.

Comment: Or `(df.index.notna().cumsum()-1)//2` of not default range index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
df['Chunk_Num'] = df.index // 2
```

Or

```
df['Chunk_num'] = (df.index.notna().cumsum()-1)//2
```

Output:

```
   Chunk_Num  reading_id      imei
0          0           4  35475624
1          0           6  35475624
2          1           6  35475624
3          1           7  35475624
4          2           7  35475624
5          2          11  35475624
```

Comment: Excellent, thank you so much.

I need to clarify something ,though: 
when I write:

```for index,row in df.iterrows():
 df['Chunk_Num']= index//2
```,
all the entries in the `Chunk_Num` column become 2. 
Thus, what is the difference between   `df['Chunk_Num']= index//2` and `df['Chunk_Num']= df.index//2`?

Comment: Inside your for loop you are assign the entire column Chunk_Num each iteration loop.  Hence the last loop's value get set to all rows.  I thin you were trying to do this row['Chunk_Num'] = index  // 2...

Comment: I see.... Could you please point out why one of the following statements , would conceptually be preferred over another, to replace the value of `df['Chunk_Num']` at the current index ?

`row['Chunk_Num'] = index // 2` versus `df.at[index,'Chunk_Num']= index//2'? The latter option is what I earlier tried to use, giving me wrong results.

Comment: @sandra16 df.at.. statement should work also as long as you have the default range index.